# Problemas ao acessar atributos de classe ao criar action listener com java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, actionlistener

Bom eu tenho uma classe que estende um `JPanel`, nesse `JPanel` eu adiciono um `JButton` e utilizo o método `addActionListener` para setar um `ActionListener` pra esse `JButton`, mas quando estou criando o `ActionListener` não consigo acessar os atributos do `JPanel`, segue o código abaixo:

```
public class MemoriaView extends JPanel {
    private GenericAPI api;
    private JButton salvar;

public MemoriaView(){
    super();
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    this.setSize(500,600);
    this.api = new GenericAPI<MemoriaModel>();
    this.salvar = new JButton("Salvar");
    this.salvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                        /* Aqui quero pode acessar o this.api porem nao consigo */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar os atributos da classe `MemoriaView` você precisa usar `MemoriaView.this.atributo` para especificar que o `this` a que você se refere é o da classe mais externa. O `this` naquele contexto é o próprio `ActionListener`.

Seu código ficaria:

```
public class MemoriaView extends JPanel {
    private GenericAPI api;
    private JButton salvar;

    public MemoriaView(){
        super();
        this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
        this.setSize(500,600);
        this.api = new GenericAPI<MemoriaModel>();
        this.salvar = new JButton("Salvar");
        this.salvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                MemoriaView.this.api.metodo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```